# PHP contact form blank with no results

Tags: php, html, web, contact-form

When I submit the formet it appears ablank contact.php page without result and without sending the mail.

Here is the contact.php :

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $fname = $_POST['first'];

        $lname = $_POST['last'];

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $from = ' Info Bank contact ';

        $to = 'infobankml@gmail.com';

        $subject = 'contact form ';

        $body = "From: " .$fname . "\n". $lname . "E-Mail: ". $email."\n". " Message:" ."\n". $message;

       

 

 

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){

        header('location : success.html');

    }

     else

     {

     header('location : fail.html');

     }

   

    }

 

?>
```

And this is the html form :

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="form">

                            <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>

                           

                            <fieldset>

                                <input placeholder="Your first name" type="text" name="first" required>

 

                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>

                                <input placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="last" required>

 

                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>

                                <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="email" required>

 

                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>

                                <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" required></textarea>

 

                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>

                                <button name="submit" type="submit" name="submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>

                            </fieldset>

                        </form>
```

Comment: you get nothing in $_POST['submit'] because is a button, not a input

Comment: @Roy it does not matter that he use button, in button it is type="submit" so its ok, it have to submit form. Maybe his fail.html is empty.

Comment: open error reporting and then check if you are getting any errors. // to enable error reporting - 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "on");